# My postgresql docker container is using all the ram and acting weird

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, devops, postgresql-13

I am using a docker compose on a 2GO digitalOcean server to deploy my app, but I noticed that the postgresql container was using all the ram available for him !
This is not normal and I wanted to know how to fix this problem..?
So I go in the logs of the container (docker logs postgres) and I found this:

[postgresql container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITUJ4.png)

I didn't expect to have logs after 'database is ready to accept connections' logs are like if I didn't have package installed in the container, but I am using the official image so I think it should work...

To help you to help me haha:

my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services: 
    monapp:
        image: registry.gitlab.com/touretchar/workhouse-api-bdd/master:latest
        container_name: monapp
        depends_on: 
            - postgres
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        command: "npm run builded-test"
        restart: always
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: 0.25
                    memory: 500M
                reservations:
                    memory: 150M
    postgres:
        image: postgres:13.1
        container_name: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        volumes: 
            - postgres_datas:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
            - postgres_dumps:/home/dumps/test
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        restart: always
        deploy:
            resources:
                limits:
                    cpus: 0.25
                    memory: 500M
                reservations:
                    memory: 150M


volumes:
  postgres_datas:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/util/databases/pgDatas
      o: bind
  
  postgres_dumps:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: $PWD/util/databases/test
      o: bind
```

and output of docker stats there:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Hiz.png)

If you have ideas ! thanks by advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution, it was because my container was compromised!

Indeed my container with postgres had an open port on 5432 to internet, so everyone could connect to it using the digitalocean droplet ip and port (:port), and I think someone was hacking my container and was using all my Ram/cpu allow to the container!

I am sure about this beaucause to correct the problem, I blocked access to the container from outside of my droplet by adding a firewall rule with iptables (you should add the rule in chain DOCKER-USER), and since I add the rule, ram consumption of the container is back to normal, and I Don t have the weird logs I published in my question anymore!

Conclusion: be careful of your Docker container security when they are running on web!

Thanks hope it helps someone :)